# .NET building process and linking

Tags: c#, .net, build, compilation, linker

Building is the sequence composed of compiling and linking.

In .NET the source code is compiled into the assembly that contains Common Intermediate Language and type info. At run time the JIT compiler converts the CIL code into  native code.

I do not understand, in .NET ,how and when the linking is occurring.

Can someone please explain the process ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *linking*?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev [Linker (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)

Comment: @Nacereddine are you author of this question?

Comment: http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/linkdefn.htm

Comment: in c++ : [linking](http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/linkdefn.htm)   ( also see lhttp://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)         I wanted to know about that process in .NET

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no linking in terms of C++.

I mean, there's no any intermediate "obj"/"lib" files, that can be distributed and linked with another "obj" files later. Reference to an assembly always has dynamic behavior (always dynamic-link library), as opposed to C++ static linking.

Something **like** linking is a creation of `.netmodule`. You can build .NET source code with compiler into `.netmodule` instead of assembly (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx), especially section ["Differences Between C# Compiler and C++ Compiler Output"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx#vcconcommand_linebuildinganchor3)), and later you can link these modules together into a single assembly (see [al.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

But this is uncommon practice - most of assemblies contains single module, and this work (source -> module -> assembly) has been done by compiler (e.g., `csc.exe`) behind the scenes. Also, I can't remember any product being redistributed as a set of `.netmodule` (not as a set of **assemblies**).

Comment: I would add that the reason there's no linking like in C++ is that there's no way to compile each file separately - the whole project has to be compiled at once. The compilation unit is a whole project, not an inididual file. This is because there can be dependencies between individual files - A can refer to B and B can refer to A. C++ solves this by having header files, so if A uses B, the header of B is included into A and it can be compiled whole. There's no such thing in C#.

Comment: This has upsides and downsides, although I would argue that the upsides are greater than the downsides as C# build times are generally smaller than C++ build times even for a whole project, even though all files have to be compiled at once even if only one changed. So this is the downside of the C# approach. However the upside is that unlike in C++, where header files are compiled multiple times for every source file they are included in - so it's wasted work compiling the same thing over and over again, in C# everything is always only compiled once.